# Are there any missable events?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I know birthdays and festivals will happen every year, but are there events with different people that are completely missable if not done by a certain time in game?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. One of the characters dies in the game. If you don't complete that character's events before then you'll have missed them.

> Specifically the character Eda dies. Like your other farming rivals she has
>  [rival events](http://harvestmoon.wikia.com/wiki/Eda_(SoS)) that are triggered by reaching a certain number friendship
>  points and reputation points. These events can also only be triggered at
>  certain times an places. You have until the end of Fall of the first year
>  to complete these events as she dies the next day on Winter 1.

You can also apparently miss flower events of your chosen marriage candidate if you attempt a reverse ring exchange. Normally the marriage process requires that you give him or her a commitment ring before the last two flower events are unlocked, but you can instead have the candidate give you a ring instead. To do this you need to give the candidate a lot of gifts. I'm not sure why exactly but [it's been reported](http://fogu.com/hmforum/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=165822) that this can cause you to miss flower events if the gifts are good ones, since after the reverse exchange you'll be at a pretty high flower level.

Comment: @Rapitor I don't really think the fact that someone dies is itself a spoiler. It's not unprecedented in Harvest Moon. Your edit forces anyone wanting a clue what's missable to have this completely spoiled.